# Can CC0 code use a GPL library?

Tags: licensing, gpl

Suppose my code uses (simply links to) a library licensed under the [GPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html). Can I release *my code* under [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/) (public domain dedication)? Is my code affected by the copyleft nature of the GPL?

Comment: @Martin Beckett: Edit the question as you want, remove trolling words, etc., but keep general sense, please.

Comment: @MartinBeckett - Just edited as you suggested.  GPL-virus is _not_ the correct term for the viral nature of the GPL.  Kinda funny, but not the right term.

Comment: @GlenH7 - yes it is a "viral" license but "gpl-virus" is a bit flame bait. There are a lot of anthropological terms for people that are correct but you wouldn't use in a bar in certain neighbourhoods!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the library is under the regular GPL, then your CC0 code cannot use it (at least [according to the GPL FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0-faq.html#IfLibraryIsGPL)). The main intention of the GPL is to prevent proprietary software makers from profiting from free software without giving back anything. If it were possible to put a program that uses GPL code under a license that does not require making the entire program open source, then the GPL could be trivially circumvented by writing wrapper for the GPL code that has a very permissive license.

There is a separate license, the [LGPL](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License) that puts a library's code under the GPL while allowing non-GPL code to use that library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to release the whole program under GPL. But nothing prevents you to release the additional source code that you wrote under CC0 as well (it is your code, you can give as many permissions on it as you wish).

However, if you distribute a binary for your software, it can only be distributed under the GPL to meet with the conditions of this license.

Similar to your situation would be an American public servant contributing to a GPL software. Their contribution is automatically in the public domain but the full software continues to be licensed under GPL. See this reference : https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0-faq.en.html#GPLUSGovAdd

Answer (score -1):

If your code uses someone else's GPL (ie not LGPL) code then you have (probably) created a derived work. The only license you have to distribute the other person's GPLed work is GPL.

You cannot take their work and give it away as CC - it's not yours!

edit: If you merely wish to release you own code on it's own (eg as source) then even if that requires your users to get the GPL lib to use it, that is fine. You can do whatever you want with your code.
What you can't do is take the combination of GPL+yours and give away the result,  eg a compiled program, as CC.

Comment: There are many different ways that once piece of code can "use" another, not all of which count as creating a derived work.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt - yes but it's likely that if the OP says they are "using a library" they are creating a derived work.

Comment: I don't want to release GPL code under CC0. I want to release only *my code* (my files) under CC0. All the same?

Comment: @user14284 - ok I expanded the answer

Comment: @Martin: except your expanded answer is now wrong.

Comment: @GlenH7 - it depends, if I post a code snippet on SO showing how to do something with lib X, that post is CC - it doesn't have to be released under lib X'es license. Obviously if I use code from within the GPL lib then that is a derived work - but is posting code that requires another lib is any different from requiring Windows7 ?

Comment: My code uses only link to library (e.g. call of `some_function_from_lib()`). But third man can use *other* implementation (suppose CC0) of the function. Why *purely my code* with links to some functions must infected with GPL, if **I** use GPL implementation of those functions?

Comment: @user14284 - I would say not, so long as you are only distributing source, not a binary (Richard Stallman may disagree). Remember if you are only using it yourself - not distributing it - then you can do anything.

Comment: I have removed my down-vote and my comments as I did a little more research and realized that I was wrong in my statements.  Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @GlenH7 - actually we do a similar run-around on a FOSS (BSD) project where we split out the bits that uses potentially patented algorithms and let the user download those separately - so it's their lawyer's problem!

Comment: @user14284: If your code links to a GPL library, and you distribute your code, it must be GPL. At least the guys who wrote the GPL very explicitly say so (see link in my answer).

Comment: but then its ok, code does not link.